# angular $http post No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' (with laravel)

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm using xampp web server and my $http get works, but even after setting the correct header the post methods are not working in any way!

My angular post:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $.param($scope.hero),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            location.reload();
        }).error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('This is embarassing. An error has occured. Please check the log for details');
        });
```

my form HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{form_title}}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form name="frmheroes" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">

                                <div class="form-group error">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Fullname" value="{{name}}" 
                                        ng-model="hero.name" ng-required="true">
                                        <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmheroes.name.$invalid && frmheroes.name.$touched">Name field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="description" class="form-control" id="description" name="description"
                                        placeholder="Hero Description" value="{{description}}" 
                                        ng-model="hero.description" ng-required="true">
                                        <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmheroes.description.$invalid && frmheroes.description.$touched">Valid Description field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Avatar</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="avatar" name="avatar" placeholder="Avatar" value="{{avatar}}" 
                                        ng-model="hero.avatar" ng-required="true">
                                    <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmheroes.avatar.$invalid && frmheroes.avatar.$touched">Avatar field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" ng-click="save(modalstate, id)" ng-disabled="frmheroes.$invalid">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The errors when posting:

```
angular.min.js:101 POST http://localhost/heroland/public/api/v1/heroes (anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:101n @ angular.min.js:97g @ angular.min.js:94(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:128m.$eval @ angular.min.js:142m.$digest @ angular.min.js:140m.$apply @ angular.min.js:143(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:268Pf @ angular.min.js:36Of.d @ angular.min.js:36
127.0.0.1/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/heroland/public/api/v1/heroes. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

The solution i've been trying in my server side, Laravel:

**New middleware - CORS:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

added it to my Kernel.php file:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, // <<< add this line
    ];
```

and used it in my laravel routes..

```
Route::get('/api/v1/heroes/{id?}', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'Heroes@index'));
Route::post('/api/v1/heroes', array('middleware' => 'cors','uses' => 'Heroes@store'));
Route::post('/api/v1/heroes/{id}', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'Heroes@update'));
Route::delete('/api/v1/heroes/{id}', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'Heroes@destroy'));
```

Still can't post my form to laravel. why is that? the get works great..

Comment: "The response had HTTP status code 500" — So you're getting an **internal server error**. What errors is the server recording in its logs?

Comment: @KevinB — I don't see anything in the JS that would trigger a preflight, and I'd expect the error message to mention "preflight" explicitly if there was one with an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL. I've been facing this problem for weeks, now I'm realizing I had to access my localhost as localhost and not has 127.0.0.1 like how I used to.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Use the chrome add-on to enable CORS:
[Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this package:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

**DANGER: DO NOT USE THE CODE BEYOND THIS POINT IN PRODUCTION:**

As a last resort you can add this to the top of your routes file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE");
```